# wllvm error: C compiler cannot create executables

Tags: clang, configure

I'm trying to build the LLVM bitcode of [`libosip2-4.1.0`](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/osip/) with [`wllvm`](https://github.com/travitch/whole-program-llvm).
I exported the following variables:

```
export LLVM_COMPILER=/home/oren/GIT/LatestKlee/llvm/Release/bin/clang
export LLVM_COMPILER_PATH=/home/oren/GIT/LatestKlee/llvm/Release/bin/
```

Then created a dedicated build library, and ran configure from there:

```
CC=wllvm ../libosip2-4.1.0/configure
```

However, configure script complains that `wllvm` cannot create executables:

> configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables

When I run it without `CC=wllvm` (usual compilation with `gcc`) everything works fine. What should I do? Thanks!

Comment: Could you post the generated `config.log`? It may hint of where the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that:

```
export LLVM_COMPILER=clang (works fine)
```

But **not with an absolute path**:

```
export LLVM_COMPILER=/home/oren/GIT/LatestKlee/llvm/Release/bin/clang (doesn't work)
```

Here is my final script that works fine and builds an llvm bitcode for libosip2-4.1.0:

```
wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/osip/libosip2-4.1.0.tar.gz
tar xf libosip2-4.1.0.tar.gz

mkdir build
cd build
CC=wllvm LLVM_COMPILER=clang ../libosip2-4.1.0/configure --enable-test --disable-shared
LLVM_COMPILER=clang make -j

cd ./src/test
extract-bc ./torture_test
file ./torture_test.bc
```

And the desired terminal output that proves mission accomplished:

```
./torture_test.bc: LLVM IR bitcode
```